# Bag of words a json formatted value within a SQL Server tables column?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a json formatted value inside a column (named `column2`) in my table. It looks like this:

```json
{
  "conversation_id": "projects/e44ftgAWERGaqrwgr3grg",
  "participant_id": "pCZXSAEWGFn/participants/",
  "reply_audio": {},
  "response": {
    "queryResult": {
      "action": "input.welcome",
      "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
      "diagnosticInfo": {
        "webhook_latency_ms": 593
      },
      "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
          "text": {
            "text": [
              "<speak><break time=\"50ms\"/> <prosody rate=\"90%\">For navigation <break time=\"150ms\"/> tell me where you’d like to go. <break time=\"200ms\"/> otherwise  <break time=\"50ms\"/> please say advisor</prosody> </speak>"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "intent":........
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to put all the words between the [{text}] and "]}}] element. So, ideally, I would want the output to look like this (each word is separated by a comma):

```
[For,navigation,tell,me,where,you’d,like,to,go,.,otherwise,please,say,advisor]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    sesh_id,date,
    CASE
        WHEN column1 IN ('index1')
            THEN ( REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE ( REGEXP_REPLACE(
      REGEXP_REPLACE(column2,"\\.",""),"\\?",""),"\\<SPEAK>","\\ . STALINE")
      ,"\\</SPEAK>","\\ ENDLINE ."))
            ELSE (column2)
    END ARRAY_of_words
FROM
    table1
```

Is there any fast way to accomplish this task? Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post a complete JSON example in your question.

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE` and `SENTENCES` aren't a valid in-built T-SQL functions either. Are these UDFs on your instance? Presumably, as SQL server has no inbuilt Regex support, `REGEXP_REPLACE` is a CLR function?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Latest Sql Server

Comment: For this sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=24b3ab823a3bfe216878860ba0b979d2 However it may not work for other edge cases (like the `.`) that you haven't mentioned, for longer strings, etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's XML inside JSON so you can just do `OPENJSON` and `.nodes('//text()')`

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, I just didn't try to validate that it was legal JSON or XML, or assume that the next row would be too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have XML contained inside your JSON. So first parse the JSON, then shred the XML, then split the final text into words by splitting on spaces:

```sql
SELECT s.*
FROM table2
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(column2, '$.response.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text') j
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( CAST(j.value AS xml) )) v1(x)
CROSS APPLY v1.x.nodes('//text()') v2(txt)
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(v2.txt.value('.','nvarchar(max)'), ' ') s
WHERE s.value <> '';
```

Result:

| value |
| --- |
| For |
| navigation |
| tell |
| me |
| where |
| you’d |
| like |
| to |
| go. |
| otherwise |
| please |
| say |
| advisor |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8194c3f56fe3a4c8f299558ef5d427ac)

You can also aggregate it into a JSON array by using `STRING_AGG`

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM table2
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      value = '[' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(s.value, 'json') + '"', ',') + ']'
    FROM OPENJSON(column2, '$.response.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text') j
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES( CAST(j.value AS xml) )) v1(x)
    CROSS APPLY v1.x.nodes('//text()') v2(txt)
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(v2.txt.value('.','nvarchar(max)'), ' ') s
    WHERE s.value <> ''
) j;
```

Result:

| value |
| --- |
| ["For","navigation","tell","me","where","you’d","like","to","go.","otherwise","please","say","advisor"] |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1e3e15ba5f1b1a4dd41c4a3d9272854)

If there are multiple `fulfillmentMessages` nodes then you may need to use `OPENJSON` twice.

Comment: Note you bring out `...,"go.",...` but they wanted `...,"go",".",...`.